# UnicodeDecodeError at response from speech_recognition.Recognizer().recognize_google()

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition

I'm trying to recognize a .WAV file converted from MP3 with FFMPEG but:

Code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
voice = sr.AudioFile('voice.wav')
with voice as source:
    audio = r.record(source)
r.recognize_google(audio)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "[...].py", line 30, in <module>
    r.recognize_google(audio)
File "[...]\Python37\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 845, in recognize_google
response_text = response.read().decode("utf-8")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

When I add option "errors=ignore" in decode command at line 845, came back a JSON ERROR... so I dont think thats the way. Has anyone had this problem?